# IPC : Communication of C++-program with a group of bash scripts and C++-programs

Tags: c++, c, linux, bash

On my Linux system, I have multiple **C/C++-daemons**(around 5 daemons) doing different-different tasks. At the same time, I have multiple **bash scripts** running in the system doing some system related tasks (around 7 scripts). I have one separate **C/C++-Daemon running as central error handler** which is dedicated for displaying error messages to user in proper GUI form. The error messages can come from any of the C/C++-daemon and scripts. For now, I only need `uni-directional communication from all the C/C++-daemons and scripts to central error handling C/C++-daemon`.

I am planning to implement this using **named-pipes**. Is there any better way of handling this communication scenario which is more **robust** and handle **concurrency** in a better way?

Comment: Why not use sockets for IPC. You can even use them in Bash. See here: http://hacktux.com/bash/socket

Comment: REDIS is nice for this - very fast and scalable. It has a command line  interface for your `bash` scripts, and a  `C` interface and `Perl` etc. Another advantage is that it would save your error messages across reboots for historical analysis. Basically, your clients would do `echo LPUSH something | redis-cli` and your server would do `echo BLPOP something | redis-cli` to do a blocking wait for error messages.

Answer (score 0):

You can either reinvent it using some low level protocol, named pipes or Unix domain sockets, or you can just rely on the standard `syslog`. It is immediately useable in C/C++ (`syslog`), in any shell (`logger`), and the daemon `syslogd` is configurable enough to send messages corresponding to a dedicated facility to a program.

My advice is to use one the the local facilities not used on your system (say `local6`) and add this to the file `/etc/syslog.conf`:

```
 # Pipe all local6 messages to the supervisor command
 local6.*           | /path/to/supervisor/command
```

You have just to write the supervisor command : it receives lines form its standard input and pass them to your daemon - here you will have to use a low level mechanism

Cons:

- you have to  write the intermediary *supervisor command*
- the *supervisor command* will be run under the user running syslogd (normally root)
- you have to be admin on the machine or ask the admin to configure syslog for you

Pros:

- syslog is a well known robust piece of code that will deal with concurrent writes for you
- the writing of messages only uses standard tools and libraries
- you get *for free* multiple message levels
- you get *for free* the possibility of storing messages to disk depending on the level
- you get *for free* the possibility of sending messages by mail depending on the level